# Python Selenium - How To Click a Non Button Element

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Ive Been Trying to Click a Button on https://blockchain.coinmarketcap.com/chain/bitcoin But With No Success (Shown in photo below).
I Couldn't even get the element I wanted to click.
If someone can help me find the element and how to click it, it would be very helpful to me.
Thanks in advance.
[The Button Im trying to click is the page 2 button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZTDN.png)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to wait until the element is presented on the page, then scroll to it and then click on it.
I tried to do it as following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

pagination_2_el_xpath = '//li[@class="ant-pagination-item ant-pagination-item-2"]'

pagination_2_el = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, pagination_2_el_xpath)))

time.sleep(0.1)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(pagination_2_el).perform()

pagination_2_el.click()
```

Also it's better to click on "next page" button so you can use this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

next_page_css = 'li.ant-pagination-next'

next_page = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, next_page_css)))

time.sleep(0.1)

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(next_page).perform()

next_page.click()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!, i do got another question tho, when i try to take the elements of the second page with soup.find.all after i clicked the next page button it still gives me the elements of the first page. why is that?

Comment: Well, first since I answered the questions please accept the answer. As you mentioned now you have some new question, so you should open a new question for that. Here on stackoverflow each question should ask a single specific question. Otherwise moderators will close is.

Comment: When you asking the new question please give more information: what exactly have you tried, what is the error etc.

Comment: Oh Sorry My Bad.
Thanks

Comment: No problem. I just wish to help you. As you can see this question is already closed since you didn't provide enough minimal information in you question.